# How to display multiple thumbnails while uploading images in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#documentUpload')
        .attr('src', e.target.result)

    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
      <img id="documentUpload" src="#" alt="first image" />
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
      <img id="documentUpload" src="#" alt="second image" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>

> Blockquote
```

" In example , click on any choose image button but image will be displayed in first case only . I changed the id in both case and in javascript as well but it didnt work.
 code above is solution to how to display image in html  "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is ID require be unique. In this example, I add an attribute called `document-up`, and it works. It's possible in this case select more than one element using attributes or classes.

```js
function readURL(input,option) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      if (option == 1){
         $("#documentUpload1")
         .attr('src', e.target.result)
       } else {
         $("#documentUpload2")
        .attr('src', e.target.result)  
       }
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="input1" type='file' onchange="readURL(this,1);" />
      <img id="documentUpload1" document-up src="#" alt="first image" />
    </li>

    <li>
      <input id="input2" type='file' onchange="readURL(this,2);" />
      <img id="documentUpload2" document-up src="#" alt="second image" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its working but same images are getting uploaded.I want different image

Comment: @user31502, I edited the code for your case, passing an option to find the target of image.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that will work for an arbitrary number of images and an arbitrary number of images per file-picker.

All you need to is wrap the #previewHolder div with a form and handle its submission.

```js
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function allByTag(tag,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByTagName(tag)}


// useful for HtmlCollection, NodeList, String types
function forEach(array, callback, scope){for (var i=0,n=array.length; i<n; i++)callback.call(scope, array[i], i, array);} // passes back stuff we need

// callback gets data via the .target.result field of the param passed to it.
function loadFileObject(fileObj, loadedCallback){var a = new FileReader();a.onload = loadedCallback;a.readAsDataURL( fileObj );}


window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 byId('addBtn').addEventListener('click', onAddBtnClicked, false);
}


/* html below function needs to create - we dont bother with the img here, since we create as needed when file/s picked */
/*
  <div class='item'>
   <img height='100px' width='100px'/><br>
   <input type='file'/>
  </div>
*/
function onAddBtnClicked(evt)
{
 var wrapper = newEl('div');
 wrapper.className = 'item';
// var img = newEl('img');
// img.style.height = '100px';
// wrapper.appendChild(img);

 var input = newEl('input')
 input.type = 'file';
 
 // input.multiple = 'true';   // file-inputs are single-selection only be default.
 
 input.addEventListener('change', onFileChanged, false);
 input.name = 'inputFiles[]';   // all inputs to get same name. Name to include [] so php can retrieve all files
 wrapper.appendChild(input);
 
 byId('previewHolder').appendChild(wrapper);
}

function onFileChanged(evt)
{
 var numFiles = this.files.length;
 var itemWrapper = this.parentNode;
 var fileInput = this;
 
 if (numFiles == 0)
 {
  // no files chosen, so remove this preview/file-picker element
  var previewHolder = itemWrapper.parentNode;
  previewHolder.removeChild(itemWrapper);
 }
 else
 {
  // remove all/any existing images
  while (allByTag('img', itemWrapper).length != 0)
   itemWrapper.removeChild( allByTag('img', itemWrapper)[0] );
   
  forEach(this.files, loadAndPreviewImage);
  
  function loadAndPreviewImage(fileObj)
  {
   loadFileObject(fileObj, onFileObjLoaded);
   
   function onFileObjLoaded(evt) //.target.result;
   {
    var img = newEl('img');
    img.style.height = '100px';
    img.src = evt.target.result;
    itemWrapper.insertBefore(img, fileInput);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```css
.item
{
 border: solid 1px black;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 4px;
}
.button:hover
{
 background-color: #b0ffb0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <div id='previewHolder' style='width: 200px'>
  <div class='button' id='addBtn' style='text-align:center;padding: 4px'><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="32" width="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
 <g transform="translate(0 -1020)" stroke="#00c03b" fill="none">
  <circle cx="16" cy="1036" r="14.5" stroke-width="2.998"/>
  <path d="m8 1036h16" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3"/>
  <path d="m16 1044v-16" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3"/>
 </g>
</svg></div>
 </div>
```